# Which GC algo is used by default in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection, java-7

I was studying about GC in Java. I came to know that from java 9 G1 (Garbage first) GC is default garbage collector. I want to know which is default GC algo for Java 7 and Java 8. Is it CMS (Concurremt Mark Sweep).

Comment: ParallelGC is for java-8

Comment: Answer depends on which JVM implementation you're using and which type of machine you're running on.